# Configure Apache (http.conf) in Chef

Tags: apache, automation, chef-infra

I'm quite a newbye in using Chef: I need to configurate my Apache on CentOS 7
so I've created a little recipe named `post_inst_config.rb` that I put in my Chef runlist in this way ...

```
"recipe[mapserver_install::inst_apache2]",
"recipe[mapserver_install::post_inst_config]"
```

Here you're my `post_inst_config.rb`

```
#Add to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf the string: ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
File.open("/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf", 'a') do |file|
  file.write "ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/"
  file.write "\n"
end

#Define the following symblink: ln -s /usr/bin/mapserv /var/www/cgi-bin/mapserv
link '/usr/bin/mapserv' do
  to '/var/www/cgi-bin/mapserv'
end

#Create the directory for the imagepath ...
directory '/var/www/html/output' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

#Restart apache  ....
service "httpd" do
  action :restart
end
```

When I try to execute my Chef cookbook I obtain this error ...

```
  ================================================================================
  Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mapserver_install/recipes/post_inst_config.rb
  ================================================================================

  Errno::ENOENT
  -------------
  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Note that if I try to execute my run list without the `post_inst_config.rb` Apache is installed and works fine.

Suggestions are appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a two-pass issue, see https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for the specifics but basically things aren't happening in the order you think they are. Either move that code in to a `ruby_block` resource (though note that you aren't checking if that line exists already so it will re-add it every run) or us something like the `poise-file` cookbook or `line` cookbook which have resources for modifying files. We really don't recommend this style of modifying files in place, it is a lot easier and safer to use a `template` resource to control the whole file contents at once.